# Regular Expression matching customer number strings

Tags: regex, vb.net

Using VB.NET, I have created an AddIn for Autodesk Inventor and the customer has a bunch of drawing number strings which follow this sort of scheme:

> 1. P01867-13-TP09-001-4950-1775-1175-895-1125-835
> 2. P01867-13-TP09-002-4950-1775-1045-895-1035
> 3. P01867-13-TP02-019-L-1137-275-852-102
> 4. P01867-13-TP02-019-L-1137-275-852-102
> 5. P01867-13-TP02-019-R-1137-275-852-102
> 6. P01867-13-TP02-021-L-1137-1055-1372
> 7. P01867-13-TP02-021-L-1137-535-1027
> 8. P01867-13-TP02-021-L-1137-795-1184
> 9. P01867-13-TP02-021-R-1137-1055-1372
> 10. P01867-13-TP02-021-R-1137-535-1027
> 11. P01867-13-TP02-021-R-1137-795-1184
> 12. P01867-13-TP02-025-L-1137-1315-1581
> 13. P01867-13-TP02-025-R-1137-1315-1581
> 14. P01867-13-TP03-005
> 15. P01867-13-TP02-019-L-1137-275
> 16. P01867-13-TP02-019-R-1137-275
> 17. P01867-13-TP02-019-R-1137
> 18. P01867-13-TP02-019-L-1137

In order to account for these groups of three digits within the variations I have created the following regex:

```
(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)
```

I now have to add the capability of looking for a sixth group of digits so figured I would ask here if there is a method within regex (which I may have overlooked) that will allow me to improve upon/simplify the above monster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`^P\d{5}-13-TP\d{2}-\d{3}(-(L|R|\d{4})(-\d{3,4})*)?$`

Your current regex is WAY too forgiving.  First of all, every one of your example starts with a P followed by some numbers, but you accept ANY COMBINATION of letters at the beginning. I'm assuming that `ALEX01867-13-TP02-019-L-1137` isn't a valid key, so you should take steps to reject it by using hungry quantifiers as little as possible (`*`, `+`). Using `\d{3,4}` matches a digit between 3 and 4 times, so that will
let you limit the sort of input you accept.

The same goes for the 5th group -  according to your examples, it's either `L`, `R`, or 4 digits. In Regex, that looks like this: `(L|R|\d{4})`

Next, you are using alternation (`option1|option2`) to capture the different "forms" your string comes in as, but you are repeating a bunch of stuff (for example, the `\w*\d*` at the beginning). You can limit the scope of the alternation by surrounding it in brackets (`()`). You can see this in action with the `(L|R|\d{4})` example - that whole bracket group becomes a single token that matches somewhere in a string (or doesn't).

Sometimes the string ends after the 4th group (Before the L/R group), and sometimes it doesn't. Instead of using alternation to solve this, which makes the regex VERY long, you can just surround the entire regex AFTER that point in brackets with a question mark (`an-(example)?`). This makes the entire second part optional.

Finally, your problem asks if there is a simple method to improve the regex. By ending it in `(-\d{3,4})*` you can match ANY length of additions to the end, assuming the all come in the form `-015` or `-1992` or whatever. If you knew that there was always a max of 15 numbers added to the end, you could change that star (`*`) to a max quantifier (`{,15}`). If sometimes the number only has two digits, change the `{3,4}` to `{2,4}`, etc.

[See it in action here](https://regex101.com/r/eW7qM4/2)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation/solution @devon-parsons! I do need to group each of the three-digit strings into groups in order to be able to retrieve Dimension A, B, C, D etc. from the strings that continue after the L or R values - does that make sense?

Comment: With repeated groups, you can only capture the final group that gets captured - so currently, your first line would capture `-835`. If you need ALL of them, you can capture EVERYTHING after the L/R by putting brackets around it and using your programming language of choice to split on the `-` characters to get the different groups.

Comment: To be clear, that means you would surround `(-\d{3,4})*` with brackets to make the entire string read `^P\d{5}-13-TP\d{2}-\d{3}(-(L|R|\d{4})((-\d{3,4})*))?$`. One of the capture groups will look like `-001-002-003-004` etc. if you feel like it, look up non-capturing groups (`?:`) to tidy it up.

Comment: So I have cobbled together this: (?'DrawingNumber'^P\d{5}-\d{2}-TP\d{2}-\d{3})-?(?'Hand'L|R)?-?(?'Dimensions'(-?\d{2,})*)-?(?'Type'1|2)?$ based on your suggestions which looks like it can account for the Drawing Number, Hand (if one exists), the Dimensions if applicable and lastly a type (1 or 2) if applicable - https://regex101.com/r/eF3hC1/2 - Thanks again!